# Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]?' to expected argument type 'Float'

Tags: swift, option-type, arkit

I am trying to do a division to calculate the scale to enlarge or shrink the node for my AR project. However I am encountering the compile error of `Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]?' to expected argument type 'Float'`.

I know the error occurs because number is an optional parameter, I tried several different ways but I could not unwrap it to the float type. How do I unwrap this?

```
guard let touchPositionInFrontOfCamera = getPosition(ofPoint: indexTip2, atDistanceFromCamera: self.distance, inView: self.sceneView) else { return }

for node in sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes{
    let distance = SCNVector3(
        touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.x - node.position.x,
        touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.y - node.position.y,
        touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.z - node.position.z
    )
    let radius: Float = sqrtf(distance.x * distance.x + distance.y * distance.y + distance.z * distance.z)
    print(node.geometry?.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: ["radius"]), radius)
    let number = node.geometry?.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: ["radius"])
    print(radius / number)
}
```

Comment: what does print(node.geometry?.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: ["radius"]), radius) prints? @tonywang

Comment: Output example `Optional(["radius": 0.382940411567688])`

Comment: Why are you calling [`NSObject.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1411319-dictionarywithvalues) in the first place?

Comment: @Alexander Because I need to create a sphere in real time which I do not know the radius unless I check it using this method

Comment: That's not the method you want. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were headed down the wrong path. The method [`NSObject.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1411319-dictionarywithvalues) exists for *the express purpose* of making a dictionary out of the receiver object's property values (for the given property names). You've asked for this, and now you're wondering "how do I get rid of this dictionary stuff?".

Well the answer is simple: don't make this dictionary you need, in the first place! Just access the property directly.

In this case, it's just a touch trickier because `SCNNode.geometry` returns a general `SCNGeometry` type, which has no radius (think about it, if it were a cube, what would its radius be? It's non-sense). So in this case, you'll need to down-case the general `SCNGeometry` type into a more narrow type, probably [`SCNSphere`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnsphere).

```
for node in sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes {
    let distance = SCNVector3(
        touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.x - node.position.x,
        touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.y - node.position.y,
        touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.z - node.position.z
    )
    let radius: Float = sqrtf(distance.x * distance.x + distance.y * distance.y + distance.z * distance.z)
    let number = (node.geometry as? SCNSphere).radius
    print(number, radius)
    print(radius / number)
}
```

You also have a lot of boiler plate here, you should make yourself some helper functions and operators to clean this up:

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    func distance(to target: other) -> SCNFloat {
        (target - self).magnitude()
    }

    static func - (a: SCNVector3, b: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        SCNVector3(a.x - b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z)
    }

    var magnitude: SCNFloat {
        (x*x + y*y + z*z).squareRoot()
    }
}

for node in sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes {
    guard let sphere = (node.geometry as? SCNSphere) else {
       // FIXME: the geometry wasn't a sphere, after all! Handle it.
       fatalError()
    }

    let radius = node.distance(to: touchPositionInFrontOfCamera)
    let number = sphere.radius
    print(number, radius, radius / number)
}
```

Look how simple that became.

Comment: I selected this answer because it offered the most detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`dictionaryWithValues(forKeys` returns `[String:Any]` you can't make it in division with a `Float`

```
guard let res = node.geometry?.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: ["radius"]), let number = res["radius"] as? Float else { return } 
print(radius / number)
```

BTW according to your geometry you can easily get the radius see

```
if let sphere = node.geometry as? SCNSphere { 
    print(sphere.radius) 
}
```